# Why some tags are not supported in current version of HTML, then what is the use of those tags?

Tags: html

Why some tags are not supported in current version of HTML, then what is the use of those tags ?

Comment: What tags are you referring to? You can always define the version of html you use in your code.

Comment: So that those who are not using the `latest version` can use them

Comment: Can you be more specific? Deprecated elements should simply not be used anymore. They are of *no* use anymore.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML5, HTML pages will not have a version number, and a previously created HTML pages will never become obsolete, though new elements will supersede many older ways of doing things, hence the warnings of obsolescence. I would highly recommended to use the newer elements over ones that have been deprecated.

An excerpt from chapter 2 of **Unraveling 2-in-1: Unraveling HTLM5, CSS3, and JavaScript + Unraveling Bootstrap 3.3** explains it pretty well:

**The Unordinary Story of HTML5**
HTML is an acronym for Hypertext Markup Language. Although it had started its life as a document description language for sharing research papers at CERN (European Organization for Nuclear Research), it became the basic technology of rendering web pages. Since its emerge in 1980, it went through many modifications, while it reached the HTML 4.0 state at the end of 1997, when it was published as an official W3C (World Wide Web Consortium) 
Recommendation.

**From HTML to XHTML**
Even W3C did not believe that HTML will survive the next century, so instead of moving forward with HTML, they stopped working on it. W3C bet on HTML’s renovated successor, XHTML (Extensible Hypertext Markup Language) that was to be built on XML. The main reason behind this decision was to enforce stricter syntax rules than required by HTML. For example, the following markup that makes the second word boldfaced is totally valid in HTML:

```
< p > Hello < b > HTML! </ p > </ b >
```

Browsers accept it, and display exactly what the creator of this markup is intended to show, although its perfunctory syntax is not valid. The right— and so valid— version was where the closing `</ p >` and `</ b >` tags would follow the proper nesting:

`< p > Hello < b > HTML! </ b > </ p >`

This second style follows the strict XML syntax rules, required by XHTML. Just think over the advantages what an XML-compliant markup such as XHTML could result. XML can be easily parsed and processed— without dealing with the quirks of HTML (such as the nesting issue in the “Hello HTML!” markup), easy integration with XML tools, portability to different devices including mobile, and so on.

Well, at the beginning XHTML seemed to be the right direction, because more and more professional developers and web designers accepted it as a standard.

Of course, browsers also parsed it, and displayed XHTML pages as demanded by the standard. However, browsers did more: they did not enforce the very strict rules, and instead spitting out error messages, they simply rendered the web page autocorrecting the improper markup— such as exchanging the `</ b >` and `</ p >` tags in the sample above.

This kind of deliberate behavior torpedoed the XHTML standard, because browsers processed old-fashioned HTML pages called XHTML. W3C thought that tightening up the strict rules and requiring browsers to reject invalid pages in XHTML 2 would solve the issues with standardization. Well, they were wrong. Not only the too many small— actually logical— changes in the standard made it fail, but the extremely slow cadence of getting forward turned developers away from it. After five years, in 2004, XHTML 2 seamed to reach a dead-end.

**The Emerging HTML5**
In the very same year, a group of enthusiastic people at Mozilla Foundation and Opera Software— the creators of Firefox and Opera browser, respectively— tried to lobby for transforming XHTML into a standard that provides much more development-oriented features. They intended to position the markup— that was originally created for describing documents— into a great tool for developing web applications, but they failed the W3C voting for this change. With Apple, they established the Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group (WHATWG) within W3C. The most important goal of this group was to extend the existing HTML standard with developers in mind— and still keeping backward compatibility. First they worked on add-in specifications (Web Applications 1.0, Web Forms 2.0).

In 2007, W3C indirectly admitted its failure when it disbanded the group working on XHTML2, and they commenced formalizing a new standard, HTML5— based on the work of WHATWG.

**HTML Forever?**
While today W3C is responsible for the official HTML5, WHATWG have not stopped visioning new HTML features. The imagine HTML as a living standard (visit [http:// developers.whatwg.org](http://%20developers.whatwg.org) for details), and the markup itself as a living language. According to this vision, HTML pages won’t have a version number, and a previously created HTML page will never become obsolete. As time goes on, and technology evolves, HTML will introduce new element and support new features. It’s up to browser vendors and developers to choose whether they will use a certain new feature or not.

Although this “living thing” seems weird— just imagine how developers would respect a moving target as new features are added to the language—, it’s actually not different what we have today with the hodgepodge of HTML features supported by different browsers. So, will it work? Time will tell...